# Collision effects in Java

Tags: java

Is it possible to add collision effects to an image in Java, drawn using the drawImage() method ? If so, how could I do it? 
Example:

```
  import java.awt.Graphics2D;
  import java.awt.Rectangle; 
  import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class Racquet {
  private static final int Y = 330;
  private static final int WIDTH = 60;
  private static final int HEIGHT = 10;
  int x = 0;
  int xa = 0;
  private Game game;

  public Racquet(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  public void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - WIDTH)
        x = x + xa;
  }

  public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillRect(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -1;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
  }

  public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

  public int getTopY() {
    return Y;
  }
}
```

Ball class:

```
    import java.awt.Graphics2D;
    import java.awt.Rectangle;

  public class Ball {
  private static final int DIAMETER = 30;
  int x = 0;
  int y = 0;
  int xa = 1;
  int ya = 1;
  private Game game;

  public Ball(Game game) {
    this.game= game;
  }

  void move() {
    if (x + xa < 0)
        xa = 1;
    if (x + xa > game.getWidth() - DIAMETER)
        xa = -1;
    if (y + ya < 0)
        ya = 1;
    if (y + ya > game.getHeight() - DIAMETER)
        game.gameOver();
    if (collision()){
        ya = -1;
        y = game.racquet.getTopY() - DIAMETER;
    }
    x = x + xa;
    y = y + ya;
  }

  private boolean collision() {
    return game.racquet.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
  }

  public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
    g.fillOval(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
  }

  public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, DIAMETER, DIAMETER);
  }
  }
```

The above code detects the collision between the racquet and the ball, now, if my racquet/racket was an image, How wuold I be able to detect the collision of it with the ball? Also, are there easier ways for collision detection?(just asking)

Comment: I think you may need to make your own `update()` method in your game that checks for collisions.  It's certainly possible to override methods like `drawImage()`, I don't think it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyImage extends BufferedImage {
  int x, y, xa, ya;

  public Rectangle getBounds() {
    return new Rectangle(x, y, getWidth(), getHeight());
  }

// all other methods in raquet remain the same except you remove paint()

private Game game;

  public MyImage(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
  }

  public void move() {
    if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth() - WIDTH)
        x = x + xa;
  }

  public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    xa = 0;
  }

  public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        xa = -1;
    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        xa = 1;
  }


  public int getY() {
    return y;
  }
}
```

To start an image you read it like this

```
MyImage myImage=null;
try {
  myImage=ImageIO.read(new File(...));
}
catch (Exception ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

> How wuold I be able to detect the collision of it with the ball?

I see that you already have a `getBounds()` methods which returns a `Rectangle` object. You can use this to check for collision.

You can do it like:

```
if(racquet.getBounds().intersects(ball.getBounds()))
    //collision happens
```

If the ball must be within the racquet, then:

```
if(racquet.getBounds().contains(ball.getBounds()))
    //collision happens
```

However, if the height of your racquet object includes then length of the racquet handle, you may implement a `getHitBox()` method for the racquet something like this:

```
public Rectangle getHitBox(){
    return new Rectangle(x, Y, WIDTH, HEIGHT-handleHeight);
}
```

> Is it possible to add collision effects to an image in Java, drawn using the drawImage() method ? If so, how could I do it?

Not sure how your `drawImage()` was implemented, so I can't comment on that. However, it is definitely possible to add some "collision effects" with custom painting. Whenever a collision is detected, play the animation at specific location (which will be the location where collision occurs).

You may construct a method like:

```
playAnimation(int locX, int locY, Animation anima, int duration)
```

In this case Animation class can just play the sprites from a sprite sheet.

> Also, are there easier ways for collision detection?(just asking)

You will probably only have 1 ball and at most 4 racquets in your game. In this case, you only need to check whether the ball hits any of the racquets:

```
for(int x=0; x<allRacquets.size(); x++) 
    if(allRacquets.get(x).collidesWith(ball))
        collidedRacquet = allRacquets.get(x);
```

`CollidesWith()` method can be implemented from the collision detection approach mentioned above:

```
//implement within Racquet class
public boolean collidesWith(Ball ball){
    return (this.getBounds().intersects(ball.getBounds()));
}
```

Comment: If I am drawing an image, will the getBounds() method work for it? Example: if the paint method in racquet class is modified like this,will getBounds() work ?                                                                                                 public void paint(Graphics2D g) {
     if(x<=230)
     {
     ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon(image location);
     Image image=i.getImage();
     g.drawImage(image,x,350,null);
    }
    else
    {
        ImageIcon i=new ImageIcon(image location);
     Image image=i.getImage();
     g.drawImage(image,x,350,null);
       }
    
     }

Comment: @user7244039 If I were you, I will draw a BufferedImage instead of using ImageIcon and the proper to play animation when a collision occurs should probably be done with an observer pattern and not writing `if-conditions` in the paintComponent method. If you are writing your if-conditions within `paintComponent()`, there will be too many conditions to handle as you add more game elements. By the way, you should be invoking `paintComponent()`, and not `paint()`.